# Form failed when called

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

in oracle form builder my form does not access trigger named WNFI i call it on when- new- form-instance like this

```
execute_trigger('WNFI') ;
```

it doesn't enter it at all 
what is the problem ?

Comment: `execute_trigger()` has been deprecated for literally decades, pretty much since Forms 3 introduced proper user-defined subprograms. So is there a particular reason why you're trying to get this working, or is it just academic curiosity?

Comment: it is built in the form before i edited

Comment: Well if it's not working now that gives you the perfect reason to re-factor it.

Comment: @APC i want to make sure that it is not a problem from my modifications ,i am trying to message that trigger but i discover that form can't see it at all

Answer (score 1):

Which Forms version do you use?

I've just tried it on Forms 10g, and it works OK - trigger is called and does its job (in my test, displays a message).

Anyway, just in case you didn't understand what APC says: move code from the WNFI trigger into a procedure (not a stored procedure, in the database; create it under the **Program units** node in the Object Navigator). For example:

```
-- This is P_WNFI procedure; this code was previously in WNFI trigger
message('wnfi');
message('wnfi');
```

Modify `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger:

```
-- instead of
--   execute_trigger('WNFI');
-- use
p_wnfi;
```

If you open Forms Online Help system and search for `execute_trigger`, you'll see a note:

> `EXECUTE_TRIGGER` is not the preferred method for executing a user-named trigger. Writing a user-named subprogram is the preferred method.

If I were you, I'd do as told. `execute_trigger` might be here for backward compatibility for some time, but not *forever*. Who knows; maybe Oracle corp. does.